# Need a tag for "ssrs-2012"

Tags: discussion

Would someone with reputation be so kind as to add an "ssrs-2012" tag? By the time I build up enough, I think Microsoft will be on the next version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Created one and adding it to questions where it looks like it goes.